# Deployment error: __MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val dependent.class.invalid not found

Tags: deployment, configuration

I am facing deployment error as shown below. I searched a lot but could not find correct solution for this. What needs to be done for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a compilation error.  In my case, a variable type was changed

FROM:

webservice myClassName myVariableName;

TO:

webservice List < myClassName > myVariableName;

However, the corresponding variable type change was NOT made in the test class.

This resulted in a compilation error.  Unfortunately, the error statement does not point you to where the compilation error is occurring.

We were able to track it down only because our nightly run of test classes failed, so we knew it had to be caused by a change made the previous day.  Based on a log of the previous day's code changes, we were able to isolate it.

Hope this helps.

Mike